# Don't call "dealloc" method when I use "layoutSubviews" or "didMoveToSuperview"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dealloc

I have a XIB with UIView.
This UIView is associated (in IB) with custom class of UIView - Page1.
File's Owner of this is MainMenuController (UIViewController, of course).
I use this XIB when init controller with "initWithNibName" and add it into navController.viewControllers.

In Page1.m I write:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    NSLog(@"Page 1 did move to superview");
    mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(refreshDateAndTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) refreshDateAndTime {
    NSLog(@"second");
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Page1 dealloc called");
    [mainTimer invalidate];
    mainTimer = nil;
    [mainTimer release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When I start timer "mainTimer" by this code, method "dealloc" isn't called and object isn't unload from memory and timer is running.
If I comment lines in "didMoveToSuperview" block dealloc called and all is OK.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dealloc` will only be called when your object has no retains left (ie, after your final release).

When you create your timer, you are telling it that its target is `self`. To avoid complications later on (ie, having `self` be released from memory and your timer still active, it therefore retains `self`. ***Timers will retain their targets***.

This means there is one extra retain on your view, which means dealloc won't be called (it's still retained by the timer).

Basically, don't use `dealloc` to invalidate your timer - use something else (perhaps a method that is triggered when your timer is no longer required).